# MacBook Pro, iCloud Drive, Time Machine and Time Capsule 2

Tags: macbook-pro, icloud, time-machine, backup, time-capsule

Can I use Time Machine and Time Capsule 2 to backup not only my MacBook Pro files, apps, etc. but also the files stored on my iCloud Drive for sharing with my other MacBook Pro and others?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - Time Machine saves a snapshot of the locally synced files from iCloud so you should be able to recover them even if they are gone from iCloud.

Since one Time Machine destination can be connected to many Macs, you could cross share that was as well.